# How to new line or separators in csv?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Not to over write csv, I tried 'a' but I get no separators.

Tried to replaced 'w' with 'a', but get no separator just mismash

```
import csv


with open('csv/1.n04', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    s = "".join(row[0] for row in reader) 

a = s.count('0')
b = s.count('1')
csvFile.close()


import csv    

f = open('csv/sum1.n04', 'w')

if b>=1:
   f.write(str((a+b)/b))
else:
   f.write(str(a)) 
f.close


import os
os.remove("csv/1.n04")
print ('Klar')
```

No error messages, it just over write csv file

Comment: You should add the definitions of `a` and `b` to your question. And if I understand what you're asking, I think you're assuming that since it's a CSV file the separators will be added automatically. This is wrong, for the `open()` function is just a file, and your code shuold take care of adding the separators yourself.

Comment: Definitions of a and b added.

Comment: As I said, `a` and `b` are just numbers. You'd have to add the separators yourself.

Comment: When I put separators typ newline='' "or other in "open" I get error messages or no thing happens.

Comment: Can you add the input file and the expected output file?

Comment: File 1n4 contains zero and ones, one digit on each line. Like 0001100000100 13line in 1n04

Comment: ....and expected output?

Comment: Hey, please first review [ask] and [mcve] before continuing here.